# Linq Entity Framework grouping and joins on names, year and month

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Appliction with MYSQL and Entity Framework. I have customers making payments made to some  payment categories.  I want to develop a ledger where I have customer names and all the classes of payments with  total payments made for any particular pay category by each customer.  And I will have to group by name, year and month.  And be able to filter by year, month or customerid. I have  25 payment categories.

The solution I have  made is ancient- it makes use of 25 joins to the get the categories, sum the payments and assign these to a viewmodel.  This runs on my developing machine alright but it  fails on my server with the error

`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Too high level of nesting for select`

Can anyone give me a better approach to achieving this goal

My Code is like below

```
public ActionResult LedgerReport(int? year, int? month, int? CuId)
{
var query = LedgerYrMn(year, month, CuId);
return View(query);
}

public IEnumerable LedgerYrMn(int? year, int? month, int? CuId)
{
DateTime lastmonth = DateTime.Now;
DateTime thismonth = DateTime.Now;
DateTime thismonthstart = DateTime.Now;

if (year.HasValue && month.HasValue)
  {
lastmonth = (new DateTime(year.Value, month.Value, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value)).AddMonths(-1));
thismonth = (new DateTime(year.Value, month.Value, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value)));
thismonthstart = (new DateTime(year.Value, month.Value, 1));
                    }
var query =
( 
from bk in db.Customers

// pay category 1
join tr in db.Payments
.Where(a => a.PDate <= thismonth && a.PDate >= thismonthstart && a.paycategory.Id == 1 && a.Paid=true)
on bk.CustomerID equals tr.CustomerID into trs

// pay category 2 
join tr2 in db.Payments
.Where(a => a.PDate <= thismonth && a.PDate >= thismonthstart && a.paycategory.Id == 2 && a.Paid=true)
on bk.CustomerID equals tr2.CustomerID into trs2
        ......
  etc to the 25 payment categories.
   }

select new LedgerViewModel
 {
 food=(int?)trs.Sum(c => c.Pay) ?? 0, 
 fuel=(int?)trs.Sum(c => c.Pay) ?? 0
 .. etc
   });
  return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Comment: Please cleanup the code and format it, its horrible to read,

Comment: You obviously should group by `paycategory.Id`. Then do the pivoting in memory. By the way, always tag the type of linq you're using (entity framework?).

Comment: will you have done it differently?  I will be grateful if you could give a  pseudo code